# Rails form_tag cancel button doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, crud

I'm new to rails and trying to implement a user registration page (Create in CRUD). In addition to a submit button, I also want a cancel button so that user can click it and go back to index page. I have done the following but the cancel button still registers the user.

Haml code (`new.html.haml`):

```
=form_tag users_path, :method => :post do

    %p= label :user, :username, "User Name"
    %p= text_field :user, :username

    ... (other information)

    = button_tag "Submit", :type => 'submit'
    = button_tag "Cancel", :type => 'cancel'
```

Rails code(`users_controller.rb`):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :check_for_cancel, :only => [:create, :update]
    def create
    vals = params[:user]
    if(User.exists(vals[:username])) 
        flash[:warning] = "#{vals[:username]} already exists! Please try a new one. "
    else
        vals[:create_date] = DateTime.current
        vals.except!(:confirm_password)
        @user = User.create(vals, :without_protection => :true)
        unless @user==nil
            flash[:notice] = "#{vals[:username]} has been registered. "
        else
            flash[:warning] = "#{vals[:username]} has not been registered successfully. "
        end
    end
    redirect_to users_path
end

    ...(other CRUD methods)

def check_for_cancel
    if(params[:commit]=="cancel")
        flash[:notice] = "Registration is cancelled. "
        redirect_to users_path
    end
end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: In your `check_for_cancel` method, try using `redirect_to users_url`. Essentially, try with `_url` instead of `_path` suffix.

Comment: @theSshow It doesn't work. Actually when I crashes the website on purpose and check the debug info for params, I can't even see :commit as a key. Is that part correct?

Comment: Actually, the only button types that are legal are `submit`, `reset`, and `button` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). `cancel` is not a valid value for the `type` attribute. Perhaps you're better off just creating a link and styling a button, like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407832/how-to-create-a-simple-html-cancel-button

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand how it works but after some experimentation the following code works. 
In haml,

```
= button_tag "Submit", :type => 'submit', :name => 'submit'
= button_tag "Cancel", :type => 'cancel', :name => 'cancel'
```

In rails,

```
def check_for_cancel
    if(params.key?("cancel"))
        flash[:notice] = "Registration is cancelled. "
        redirect_to users_path
    end
end
```

Basically, when I give button a name, the `params` will have a entry `params["cancel"]=""` or `params["submit"]=""`, depending on the key being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The only button types that are legal are `submit`, `reset`, and `button` (http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). `cancel` is not a valid value for the `type` attribute.

You'll have to create a workaround to pass the "cancel" message across the button submit. See previous answer for options:
[How to create a HTML Cancel button that redirects to a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407832/how-to-create-a-simple-html-cancel-button)

Answer (score 0):

You could use link_to and style it as a button with css and then you don't have to have any check in your controllers.

```
= link_to 'Cancel', users_path, class: 'btn'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a development team that has a dedicated designer who creates the front-end markup then to work seamlessly and easily, I'll advice you use html and erb instead of haml for rendering your views. 
A simple form to achieve what you want using html and erb is

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :user_name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :phone %><br />
        <%= f.number_field :phone %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

but if you still insist on using haml cause of its brevity then

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this user from being saved:
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  .field
    = f.label :user_name
    %br/
    = f.text_field :user_name
  .field
    = f.label :first_name
    %br/
    = f.text_field :first_name
  .field
    = f.label :last_name
    %br/
    = f.text_field :last_name
  .field
    = f.label :phone
    %br/
    = f.number_field :phone
  .actions
    = f.submit
    \#{link_to 'Back', users_path}
```

As shown above the "link_to" helper method would navigate to the specified path in this case 
users_path. Find more info about the link_to helper method http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score -1):

`<%= button_tag "Cancel", type: :reset %>`  This work for me

for more ref:- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html