# How to Get Out of An HTML Form With Required Attribute

Tags: html

I used the `required` HTML tag attribute in an HTML form so the `input` tag needs to be field up before a submit.

How do I get out of the form without activating the `required` attribute because I cancelled with a `button` that goes to another form.

Comment: After realizing my work-around, I just found out that this is answered in another [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407832/how-to-create-a-html-cancel-button-that-redirects-to-a-url)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a HTML Cancel button that redirects to a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407832/how-to-create-a-html-cancel-button-that-redirects-to-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for a cancel button.

But I don't think there's a cancel button in HTML.

My work around is create and Link tag `<a>` and make it look like a cancel button.  And of course, the link will lead to another page.